# Install Pgloader in Cent OS 6.7

Tags: linux, rpm, centos6, rpmbuild, pgloader

I'm trying to install [pgloader](http://pgloader.io/download.html) on centOS **6.7 (64 bits)**

---

## Steps

```
wget http://pgsql.tapoueh.org/pgloader/pgloader-3.0.98-21.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh pgloader-3.0.98-21.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

---

## Result

> -Uvh pgloader-3.0.98-21.el6.x86_64.rpm: unknown option

---

How can I fix it ? Did I miss anything ? Do I need to install rpm or anything like that ?

Comment: looks like your rpm doesn't support all options well. Try just `rpm -i pgloader-3.0.98-21.el6.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: It works. Thanks :)

Comment: ok; I added it as answer; you can accept so others see that this problem is solved... tx

Comment: this should be updated , as it returns `ERROR 404:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like your rpm doesn't support all options well. Try just

```
rpm -i pgloader-3.0.98-21.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Actually no issues here with (as root) : # `rpm -Uvh pgloader-3.0.98-21.el6.x86_64.rpm` ...... A corrupt rpm package in @ihue´s OS ? -

Comment: @KnudLarsen; I don't think corrupt; but maybe it misunderstands some options... or maybe it complains about updating a package that wasn't installed before...

Comment: »»complains about updating a package that wasn't installed before«« : No, `rpm -Uvh` is the default install command, used by yum to install a package. ( And as well in other package managers, zypper (Suse) and "apt for rpm", urpmi, etc.)

Comment: Yeah I've been using the same command as well. I don't really understand why it failed on his PC. I proposed rpm -i to see if that worked... apparently it did...

Answer (score 0):

I achieved installing pgloader on my CentOS 6.7 by executing :

`yum install --enablerepo=*postgresql* pgloader`

`pgloader` package seems available in one PostgreSQL repo.

Comment: 'No package pgloader available' for me.